# Filter listview

Tags: android, listview, filter

Here is the code of my filter:

```
private class NameFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // NOTE: this function is *always* called from a background thread,
        // and
        // not the UI thread.
        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Place> filt = new ArrayList<Place>();
            ArrayList<Place> lItems = new ArrayList<Place>();
            synchronized (this) {
                lItems.addAll(objects);
            }
            for (int i = 0, l = lItems.size(); i < l; i++) {
                Place m = lItems.get(i);
                if (m.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                    filt.add(m);
            }
            result.count = filt.size();
            result.values = filt;
        } 
        else {
            synchronized (this) {
                result.values = objects;
                result.count = objects.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        // NOTE: this function is *always* called from the UI thread.
        filtered = (ArrayList<Place>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        for (int i = 0, l = filtered.size(); i < l; i++)
            add(filtered.get(i));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

}
```

Here is my activity code:

```
lvPlace = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final ArrayList<Place> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

    filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter_text);
    filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    adapter = new PlaceAdapter(this, 0, searchResults);

    lvPlace.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvPlace.requestFocus();
    lvPlace.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            filterEditText.getText().toString();
        } else {
            Log.d("filter", "no filter availible");
        }
    }

};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    filterEditText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
```

I've struggled with this for a while becasue when I was typing something in the search box it was working fine, but once I've removed the text from the search field, the list doesn't return to the initial state.
Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `publishResults` method:

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results)
{   
    filtered.clear();
    filtered = (ArrayList<Place>) results.values;
    if(filtered.size() < 1)
        filtered = objects;

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    for (int i = 0, l = filtered.size(); i < l; i++)
        add(filtered.get(i));
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

With this code, you can take out the else clause in your filter method.

As an extra, you can also make your for loop a bit more efficient by using a loop like this:

```
for(Place place : filtered)
    add(place);
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I was typing something in the search box it was working fine, but
>   once I've removed the text from search field list was not returning to
>   initial state.

Without seeing the code for your adapter, this most likely happens because you don't keep a reference to the initial values that are used by the adapter. For example if you set an `ArrayList` with data into the adapter and start to enter characters in the filtering `EditText` this will work because by filtering you're using only a subset of the previous set of values(which will always be available). When you delete a character from the `EditText` you need to do the filtering on the previous set of values, but as that set was replaced the values don't exist anymore and the filtering breaks.

The solution is to make a **copy** of the initial values to always have the complete `ArrayList` of values to do the filtering. One copy of the `ArrayList` will be used by the adapter(this will be the `ArrayList` that gets replaced in `publishResults` with the results of the filtering) and one will be used to do the filtering on by the filter(this `ArrayList` will remain the same!) in the `performFiltering` method.

Comment: @HùngPhiCao Did you manage to solve the problem? If not add the code for the adapter you use.